How to make table of contents with chapter summaries with tocloft?
How can I make this custom table of contents with tocloft?


My question is asking for a tocloft version of "Table of Contents with additional description of entries"

what have you tried? if tocloft doesn't work with that solution, why not just drop tocloft? you've provided no substantive reason for wanting a different implementation.

No need to use tocloft. Use \documentclass{memoir}'s \chapterprecis{}.
MWE:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My first chapter}
\chapterprecis{Summary of first chapter will appear at the beginning of the chapter and also in the table of contents.}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapterprecis{Summary of second chapter will appear at the beginning of the chapter and also in the table of contents.}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}






